# Error al autenticar usuario en express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, jwt

Estoy creando una api rest con express y con tal de proteger las rutas he intentado crear una capa de autenticación para que si el usuario no se ha creado o no está autenticado no sea posible entrar a la ruta, para la autenticación hago uso de JWT.

El problema con el que me encuentro es que al haber creado el usuario y autenticarme, cuando intento acceder a otra ruta me muestra el error: `"error": "Invalid id"` como si estuviera pasando un dato inválido, les muestro mi código:

```
//routes.config.js
const express = require ('express');

const router = express.Router();
const accessController = require('../controllers/access.controller')
const usersController = require('../controllers/users.controller')
const secureRoute = require('../middlewares/AuthRoute/secure.middleware')

router.post('/login', accessController.login)
router.post('/users', usersController.create)
router.get('/users', secureRoute.auth, usersController.list)
```

Aquí creo y listo los usuarios

```
//users.controller.js
const User = require('../models/user.model')

module.exports.create = (req, res, next) => {
    User.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        bio: req.body.bio,
        active: req.body.active,
    })
        .then((user) => {
            res.status(201).json(user);
        })
        .catch(next)
}

module.exports.list = (req, res, next) => {
    User.find()
        .then((users) => {
            res.status(200).json(users)
        })
        .catch(next)
}
```

Aquí hago el login

```
//access.controller.js
const User = require('../models/user.model')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

secret = process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY;

module.exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
        .then(user => {
            if (user) {
                user
                    .checkPassword(req.body.password)
                    .then((match) => {
                        if (match) {
                            const token = jwt.sign({
                                    sub: user.email,
                                    exp: Date.now() / 1000 + 60
                                }, secret);
                            
                            res.status(200).json({ token });
                        } else {
                            res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid credentials' })
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(next);
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' })
            }
        })
        .catch(next);
}
```

Y este es el método que utilizo para proteger las rutas

```
//secure.middleware.js
const User = require('../../models/user.model')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

secret = process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY

module.exports.auth = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split("Bearer ")[1]
        const { sub } = jwt.verify(token, secret);
        
        if (sub) {
            User.findById(sub)
                .then((user) => {
                    if (user) {
                        req.user = user
                        next();
                    } else {
                        res.status(401).json({ error: 'unauthorized: invalid user' });
                    }
                })
                .catch(next);
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({ error: 'unauthorized: missing user email' });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        if (err instanceof jwt.TokenExpiredError) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'unauthorized: token expired' })
        }else if (err instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'unauthorized: invalid token' })
        }else if (err instanceof TypeError) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'unauthorized: missing token' })
        }

        res.status(401).json({ error: 'unauthorized: initiation process failed' })
    }
};
```

La api me genera un token valido
[image: La api me genera un token]

Cuando utilizo el mismo token en una ruta protegida con `secureRoute` obtengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando creas el token asignas el email del usuario como sub:

```
const token = jwt.sign({
     sub: user.email,
     exp: Date.now() / 1000 + 60
}, secret);
```

Cuando autorizas al usuario, accedes al sub (email):

```
const { sub } = jwt.verify(token, secret);
```

Y lo usas para buscar al usuario en la base de datos por ID:

```
User.findById(sub)
```

Estás usando un email para buscar por ID, puede que ese sea el error, intenta buscarlo de la misma forma que lo haces en el login:

```
User.findOne({ email: sub })
```

Comment: Eso era lo que pasaba, ya me funciona, muchísimas gracias!!